Flutter app crashes on Android after it calls "await GoogleSignIn().signIn();"
I'm trying to signin via Google in my app on Android, and when it calls await GoogleSignIn().signIn();, my app crashes.
Here is code of signin widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Signin extends StatelessWidget {
  const Signin({super.key, required this.setIsSigned});
  final setIsSigned;

  void signin () async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn(); // crashes here

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth = await googleUser?.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
    );

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final email = userCredential.user?.email;
    final login = email?.split('@')[0];

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('/users/$login');
    final snap = await ref.get();
    final data = snap.value;

    if (data == null){
      await ref.set({
        "email": email,
      });
    }

    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (login != null){
      await prefs.setString('login', login);
    }
    
    setIsSigned(true, login);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: signin,
        child: const Text('Signin via Google'),
      )
    );
  }
}

Errors in debug console:
D/AndroidRuntime(31316): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(31316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(31316): Process: com.ms.sndst, PID: 31316
E/AndroidRuntime(31316): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=53293, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.ms.sndst/com.ms.sndst.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mresult has not been initialized
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4977)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5018)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2073)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316): Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mresult has not been initialized
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at com.media.storage.media_storage.MethodCallHandlerImpl.getMresult(MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt:60)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at com.media.storage.media_storage.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onActivityResult(MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt:291)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onActivityResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:774)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:422)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:964)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterActivity.java:911)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8249)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4970)
E/AndroidRuntime(31316):    ... 11 more
I/Process (31316): Sending signal. PID: 31316 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.

Exited.

I tried to run flutter clean and flutter pub get, I tried to delete google-services.json, firebase_options.json, firebase.json and run flutterfire configure again, but these ones didn't solve my problem.

Did you import both firebase_auth and google_sign_in packages?

Yes, I imported these packages

Can you show us how did you initialize the mresult variable?

I don't know what mresult is. I didn't initialize it anywhere.

It turns out, my app crashes because of the media_storage library. Now, I'll have to find some alternative for media_storage.
